# "Do come in." In a positive sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I was watching a movie and in a scene a character said:

> Please *do come in*.

I understood that it as an order. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: It wasn't an order, it was just an imperative sentence. The tone of the sentence is intended to be exactly the opposite of an order, like giving the connotation that the entrance of someone who's not in the room is highly suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's grammatically correct, but it sounds a little dated. I don't expect you'd hear too many people say it nowadays – most would opt for the more concise "Please, come in."

When characters say this in books and movies, the invitation often comes across as formal, sophisticated, or ominous. For example, I wouldn't be surprised to hear Sherlock Holmes say this at 221B Baker Street, and I wouldn't be surprised to hear a villian say this to James Bond, particularly if he had something up his sleeve. But I would be surprised to hear my neighbor say this if I knocked on the door and asked to borrow a cup of sugar.

Comment: Well put, J.R.; I couldn't have said it better.

Comment: So you do you mean somehow it's an irony? cause you said you will be surprised if you hear nowdays; I mean if someone want to do a bad thing like your neighbor, why would he inform you? unless it's be an irony or something like that.

Comment: @Pooria - A neighbor wouldn't say it as a warning. As I said, it sounds quaint and old-fashioned. It sounds like something I would hear in a play, rather than in actual conversation. But there's nothing wrong with it grammatically.